# laravel NotFoundHttpException when accessing the controller

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Iam new to laravel 4 .. i have a controller when trying to access `http://localhost/AppName/public/portfolio` it throws `NotFoundHttpException`

```
<?php
    class PortfolioController extends BaseController {

public function __construct(){

    $this->beforeFilter('csrf' , array('on'=>'post')) ;
 }
 public function getIndex () {

        return View::make('portfolio.index');
}    
}
?>
```

and that's my `routes.php`

```
<?php
Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'HomeController@getIndex'));
Route::controller('portfolio' , 'PortfolioController');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must likely have to update your Laravel directory
Open up the command prompt or terminal and cd into the Laravel and type this in:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

With Laravel, this command is necessary to keep the project folder "up-to-date"

Comment: I think it is because you are trying to go to '/portfolio'. Take out the portfolio part and it will go to '/'.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create function getPortfolio in your PortfolioController. As you are using get verb and trying to access portfolio you should mention getPortfolio method in its respective Controller. Try following code

```
<?php
    class PortfolioController extends BaseController {

public function __construct(){

    $this->beforeFilter('csrf' , array('on'=>'post')) ;
 }
 public function getPortfolio () {

        return View::make('portfolio.index');
}    
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to know which Server are you using ? and Have you Set up your virtual host properly. Because If localhost is your root address then you dont need to write appName/public/, as this would be already done by virtual host configuration. Also tell me if you type simply localhost then are you getting getIndex method of HomeController..?